# How to change hit point to crosshair?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Below script uses a function whereas there first is a check if there is a object in range and if it, it is.
On pressing mouse key, the projectile is shooting towards the pivot point of that said object. I want the projectile to

1. always being able to fire (indifferent if the object is in range) and
2. shoot towards the crosshair (to the screen midpoint) and NOT towards the object pivot point.

I am a novice at coding and I can't see what code to remove and what to add.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Events;

    public struct ShootHit
    {
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public Vector3 point;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class UnityEventShootHit : UnityEvent<ShootHit> { }

    [DisallowMultipleComponent, AddComponentMenu("(つ♥v♥)つ/Useables/Shoot")]
    public class ShootComponent : MonoBehaviour
    {
    [Header("Input")]
    [Tooltip("Data that determines the input of player actions")]
    [SerializeField] private InputProfile _inputProfile;
    // [SerializeField] private float _range = 100.0f;

    /* [Header("Sight Values")]
     [Tooltip("How far the the sight can reach")]
     public float sightRadius = 1f;
     [Range(0f, 360f)]
     public float fieldOfViewAngle = 100f;*/

    [Header("Charge-up")]
    [SerializeField] private float _chargeupTime = 0.5f;
    private bool _isChargingPrimary = false;
    private bool _isChargingSecondary = false;

    [Header("Aim Assist")]
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _aimAssistLayerMask;

    public float aimAssistRadius = 30.0f;  // radius
    [Range(0.0f, 360.0f)]
    public float aimAssistMaxAngleToAssist = 45.0f;  // angle

    private ShootHit? _target;

    //publics
    public Transform shootOrigin;

    [Header("Events")]
    public UnityEventShootHit OnPrimaryFire;
    public UnityEvent OnPrimaryFireStart;
    public UnityEvent OnPrimaryFireStop;

    public UnityEventShootHit OnSecondaryFire;
    public UnityEvent OnSecondaryFireStart;
    public UnityEvent OnSecondaryFireStop;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (_inputProfile == null) Debug.LogError(gameObject.name + " does not 
        have a player input");
    }

     private void Update()
     {
         // Remove target if object is too far away
         if (_target.HasValue)
         {
            if (Vector3.Distance(_target.Value.gameObject.transform.position, 
         transform.position) > aimAssistRadius)
            {
                _target = null;
            }
         }

         if (_inputProfile.GetPrimaryFireButtonDown())
         {
            StopCoroutine(ChargeUpBeforeFireSecondary());

            if (!_isChargingPrimary)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ChargeUpBeforeFirePrimary());
            }
         }

         else if (_inputProfile.GetSecondaryFireButtonDown())
         {
            StopCoroutine(ChargeUpBeforeFirePrimary());

            if (!_isChargingSecondary)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ChargeUpBeforeFireSecondary());
            }
        }

         if (_inputProfile.GetPrimaryFireButton() || 
        _inputProfile.GetSecondaryFireButton())
        {
            if (!_target.HasValue) _target = GetObjectClosestToAim();

            if (_inputProfile.GetPrimaryFireButton())
            {
                OnPrimaryFire.Invoke(_target.Value);
            }
            if (_inputProfile.GetSecondaryFireButton())
            {
                OnSecondaryFire.Invoke(_target.Value);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            _target = null;
        }

        if (_inputProfile.GetPrimaryFireButtonUp())
            OnPrimaryFireStop.Invoke();
        if (_inputProfile.GetSecondaryFireButtonUp())
            OnSecondaryFireStop.Invoke();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the object within range closest to the players forward-vector 
    using _aimAssistLayerMask.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns object closest to aim if any object is found, else 
    returns null.</returns>
    ShootHit? GetObjectClosestToAim()
    {
        // Raycast
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(shootOrigin.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, 
        out hit, aimAssistRadius, _aimAssistLayerMask))
        {
            if (hit.transform?.GetComponent<IShootTarget>() != null)
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

                return new ShootHit { gameObject = hit.transform.gameObject, 
    point = hit.point };
            }
        }

        float _closestDot = -2f;
        GameObject _closestDotObject = null;
        RaycastHit[] _hit = Physics.SphereCastAll(transform.position, 
        aimAssistRadius, transform.forward, 0, _aimAssistLayerMask, 
        QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

        // Get best dot from all objects within range
        for (int i = 0; i < _hit.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_hit[i].transform.gameObject == this.gameObject || 
        _hit[i].transform.GetComponent<IShootTarget>() == null)
                continue;

            Vector3 _dif = _hit[i].transform.position - transform.position;

            float _newDot = Vector3.Dot(transform.forward.normalized, 
      _dif.normalized);
            if (_newDot > _closestDot)
            {
                _closestDot = _newDot;
                _closestDotObject = _hit[i].transform.gameObject;
            }
        }
        if (!_closestDotObject)
            return null;

        // Make sure there are no object in the way of our best-dot-object
        Collider[] colliders = _closestDotObject.GetComponents<Collider>();
        Vector3 point = colliders[0].ClosestPoint(shootOrigin.position);
        float distanceToPoint = Vector3.Distance(shootOrigin.position, point);
        // Get closest collider
        for (int i = 1; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 newPoint = colliders[i].ClosestPoint(shootOrigin.position);
            float newDistanceToPoint = Vector3.Distance(shootOrigin.position, 
        newPoint);
            if (distanceToPoint > newDistanceToPoint)
            {
                point = newPoint;
                distanceToPoint = newDistanceToPoint;
            }
        }
        RaycastHit _rayhit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(shootOrigin.position, point - transform.position, 
        out _rayhit, aimAssistRadius, _aimAssistLayerMask))
        {
            if (_rayhit.transform.gameObject != _closestDotObject)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        Vector3 _vecToClosest = _closestDotObject.transform.position - 
    transform.position;
        if (Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, _vecToClosest) <= 
    aimAssistMaxAngleToAssist)
         {
            return new ShootHit { gameObject = _closestDotObject, point = point 
 };
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

     IEnumerator ChargeUpBeforeFirePrimary()
    {
        _isChargingPrimary = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_chargeupTime);
        _isChargingPrimary = false;
        OnPrimaryFireStart.Invoke();
    }

    IEnumerator ChargeUpBeforeFireSecondary()
    {
        _isChargingSecondary = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_chargeupTime);
        _isChargingSecondary = false;
        OnSecondaryFireStart.Invoke();
    }


    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (!Application.isPlaying) return;

        Color oldColor = Gizmos.color;

        float halfFeildOfView = aimAssistMaxAngleToAssist * 0.5f;
        float coneDirection = -90f;

        Quaternion leftRayRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-halfFeildOfView + coneDirection, Vector3.up);
        Quaternion rightRayRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(halfFeildOfView + coneDirection, Vector3.up);

        Vector3 leftRayDirection = leftRayRotation * transform.right * aimAssistRadius;
        Vector3 rightRayDirection = rightRayRotation * transform.right * aimAssistRadius;

        // Green Arc
        Handles.color = new Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 0.25f);
        Handles.DrawSolidArc(transform.position, Vector3.up, leftRayDirection, aimAssistMaxAngleToAssist, aimAssistRadius);

        Gizmos.color = oldColor;


    }
     #endif

}
`
```

This is the code attached to the projectile

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class ProjectileScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Explosion;

    public Transform Target;

    Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    public float speed = 1.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // _rigidbody.AddForce((Target.position - transform.position).normalized, ForceMode.Impulse);
        Collider targetCollider = Target.GetComponent<Collider>();
        Vector3 targetDirection;
        if (targetCollider)
            targetDirection = targetCollider.ClosestPoint(transform.position) - transform.position;
        else
            targetDirection = Target.position - transform.position;

        _rigidbody.velocity = targetDirection.normalized * speed;
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.position) < 1.0f)
        {
            //make the explosion
            GameObject ThisExplosion = Instantiate(Explosion, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

            //destory the projectile
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void SetTarget(GameObject target)
    {
        this.Target = target.transform;
    }

    public void SetTarget(ShootHit hit) => SetTarget(hit.gameObject);

}
```

This script is how and where the Projectile Spawns. It is attached to an empty gameobject located on the muzzle of the gun.

```
public class ProjectileSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject projectileInsert;

        public GameObject projectileExtract;
        public float projectileSpeed = 1.0f;

        GameObject projectile;

        public void Insert(GameObject target)
        {
            if (projectile) return;

            projectile = Instantiate(projectileInsert, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            ProjectileScript projectileScript = projectile.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>();
            projectileScript.SetTarget(target);
            projectileScript.speed = projectileSpeed;

            // Physics.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<Collider>(),
            // projectileSpawn.parent.GetComponent<Collider>()); 

        }

        public void Extract(GameObject target)
        {
            if (projectile) return;

            projectile = Instantiate(projectileExtract, target.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            ProjectileScript projectileScript = projectile.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>();
            projectileScript.SetTarget(gameObject);
            projectileScript.speed = projectileSpeed;

            // Physics.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<Collider>(),
            // projectileSpawn.parent.GetComponent<Collider>()); 

        }


    }
```

Comment: What do you want to happen with `Extract`? Do you want that to be same as before? That is a pretty substantial thing you should have mentioned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ProjectileSpawner`, add a `LayerMask` field to filter out invalid collisions (set it in the inspector) for the non-homing projectile. You'll set this in the inspector to make the non-homing projectiles collide with the desired layers:

```
public LayerMask collisionLayers;
```

In `Insert`, find the ray going from the screen's center, and use it and the `LayerMask` as a parameter to `SetTarget`:

```
public void Insert(GameObject target)
{
    if (projectile) return;

    Ray centerRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2, 0f));

    projectile = Instantiate(projectileInsert, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    ProjectileScript projectileScript = projectile.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>();
    projectileScript.SetTarget(centerRay, collisionLayers);
    projectileScript.speed = projectileSpeed;

    // Physics.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<Collider>(),
    // projectileSpawn.parent.GetComponent<Collider>()); 

}

public void Extract(GameObject target)
{
    if (projectile) return;

    projectile = Instantiate(projectileExtract, target.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    ProjectileScript projectileScript = projectile.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>();
    projectileScript.SetTarget(gameObject);
    projectileScript.speed = projectileSpeed;

    // Physics.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<Collider>(),
    // projectileSpawn.parent.GetComponent<Collider>()); 

}
```

Then in the `ProjectileScript`, add a `bool` field to remember if the projectile homes on a gameObject or if it follows a ray, a `Ray` field to remember such a ray, and a `LayerMask` field to remember what to collide with:

```
public bool isHoming;
public Ray TargetRay
public LayerMask collisionLayers;
```

Then, in `public void SetTarget(GameObject target)`, set that `bool` to `true`:

```
public void SetTarget(GameObject target)
{
    this.Target = target.transform;
    isHoming = true;
}
```

And make a new `public void SetTarget(Ray shootRay)` that remembers a `Ray` and `LayerMask` and sets the `bool` to `false`:

```
public void SetTarget(Ray shootRay, LayerMask collisionLayers)
{
    this.TargetRay = shootRay;
    this.collisionLayers = collisionLayers;
    isHoming = false;
}
```

Also, in `ProjectileScript`, you will need to change the `FixedUpdate` method to check if the bool is true, and if it is, then do the same as before. Otherwise, move along the ray and destroy it if it travels too far:

```
public float maxDistanceBeforeDestroy = 100f;

...

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isHoming) 
    {    
        // _rigidbody.AddForce((Target.position - transform.position).normalized, ForceMode.Impulse);
        Collider targetCollider = Target.GetComponent<Collider>();
        Vector3 targetDirection;
        if (targetCollider)
            targetDirection = targetCollider.ClosestPoint(transform.position) - transform.position;
        else
            targetDirection = Target.position - transform.position;

        _rigidbody.velocity = targetDirection.normalized * speed;
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.position) < 1.0f)
        {
            //make the explosion
            GameObject ThisExplosion = Instantiate(Explosion, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

            //destory the projectile
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _rigidbody.velocity = TargetRay.direction.normalized * speed;

        // Check if it has traveled too far

        if ((transform.position - TargetRay.origin).magnitude > maxDistanceBeforeDestroy ) 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add an `OnCollisionEnter` method that doesn't do anything if the projectile is homing. But if it isn't, it checks if the collision matches the `LayerMask`, and if it does, it makes the explosion and destroys the projectile:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
     if (isHoming) 
     {
         return;
     }

     if( && ((1<<other.gameObject.layer) & collisionLayers) != 0)
     {
         //make the explosion
        GameObject ThisExplosion = Instantiate(Explosion, 
                gameObject.transform.position, 
                gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

        //destroy the projectile
        Destroy(gameObject);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, highly appreciate it! When changing the block in the Shoot Component script, I receive errors on almost all other functions. Using the centerRay in the invoke the message I receive is "cannot convert from UnityEngine.Ray to 'ShootHit'

Comment: @bapeditir I realized you have to change the `UnityEventShootHit` definition, and that you will have to select the `SetTarget(Ray)` method for the `OnPrimaryFire` and `OnSecondaryFire` events. I updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: in the projectile script the SetTarget functions speaks to the public struct in the Shoot Component script.  Should I change the struct from public game object to public ray?                                                                                               public void SetTarget(GameObject target)
    {
        this.Target = target.transform;
    }

    public void SetTarget(ShootHit hit) => SetTarget(hit.gameObject);

Comment: I added the projectile spawn script in my post. This is attached to an empty game object attached to the gun.

Comment: @bapeditir I substantially changed my answer to account for the two types. I'm not sure where your code is currently at but I worked my answer assuming `public void Insert(GameObject target)` and `public void Extract(GameObject target)` are glued to the `UnityEventShootHit ` events.

Comment: Ruzihm I finally got it to work, thanks (our programmer where out for the day and you saved the day)!

Comment: @bapeditir glad to hear it. If my answer helped, be sure to click the grey checkmark and/or upvote it so people with a similar problem can find it more easily (and it also gives me some reputation points ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague and doesn't look like you have put a lot of effort into understanding the code and trying to alterate it. Anyway I'll do my best.

---

> always being able to fire (indifferent if the object is in range)`

probably simply set `aimAssistRadius = 0;` or entirely remove the check

```
if (Vector3.Distance(_target.Value.gameObject.transform.position, transform.position) > aimAssistRadius)
{ 
    _target = null; 
}
```

---

> shoot towards the crosshair (to the screen midpoint) and NOT towards the object pivot point.

The script you posted (probably not yours) seems to have the entire purpose of doing what you not want to do: Aim assist. Removing it probably changes a lot of things but the simpliest would be to simply set the `ProjectileScript._rigidbody.velocity` in the moment the projectile is instantiated. Unfortunately you didn't provide the code where this happens.

I don't see in which moment your `ShootComponent` interacts with the `ProjectileScript` but probably in one of those UnityEvents ... ?

But in general it would maybe simply look like

```
public class ProjectileScript : MonoBehaviour
{
     public float speed = 1.0f;

    private RigidBody _rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    }

    public void SetDirection(Vector3 direction)
    {
        _rigidbody.velocity = direction.normalized * speed;
    }
}
```

and whereever you Instantiate the projectile do

```
var projectile = instantiatedObject.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>();
var direction = Camera.main.transform.forward;
projectile.SetDirection(direction);
```

---

as you can see you will have to make the

```
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.position) < 1.0f)
{
    //make the explosion
    GameObject ThisExplosion = Instantiate(Explosion, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

    //destory the projectile
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

happen somewhere else since the code will not be target based anymore ... I would probably use [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) instead something like e.g.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{ 
    // maybe only collide with a certain tag
    if(collision.gameObject.tag != "Target") return;

    //make the explosion
    GameObject ThisExplosion = Instantiate(Explosion, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

    //destory the projectile
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```